# Any idea why I'm getting a runtime error here?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Doing [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/largest-permutation?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) on HackerRank and my O(n) solution is passing all the test cases besides the last three, which it is failing with a **Runtime Error**. Unfortunately, I have no way of seeing what the runtime error is. When I run the tests in Visual Studio I get no errors. Any idea what could be causing the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution
{
    public static void Swap(int[] A, int i1, int i2)
    {
        int temp = A[i1];
        A[i1] = A[i2];
        A[i2] = temp;
    }
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] parameters = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
        int n = parameters[0];
        int k = parameters[1];
        int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
        int[] pos = new int[n + 1]; // pos[m] is the index of the value m in arr
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
        {
            pos[arr[i]] = i;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length && k > 0; ++i, --n)
        {
           if(arr[i] == n) 
               continue;
           int j = pos[n];
           Swap(pos, arr[i], n);
           Swap(arr, i, j);
           --k;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: After you fail tests, they do allow you to "purchase" the input and expected output from the test case, using some of the point you earn on the site. I know that's not quite what you asked but it's an option to consider.

Comment: I would guess invalid `int` input?

Answer (score 0):

below partial code is wrong, because user can enter three number such as 15, 20, 22, `array.length` is 15 but you want access to index 15, 20, 22...
if you want access to these indexes should set length of `pos` to max number.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
{
    pos[arr[i]] = i;
}
```

**edit1:**
for more guide, please say line of code and message of run time error.

Comment: The problem description the OP links to states that the second line of input will be a permutation of the first `N` integers, `N` being one of the parameters supplied on the first line. If such input was given then the input's out of line with the spec and so the program wouldn't be expected to act sensible.